# Is it possible to loop through a set of colors with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have this:

```
var colors = [ 'BlueViolet', 'CadetBlue', 'Coral', 'Crimson', 'DarkGoldenRod', 'DarkOliveGreen'],
    a = document.getElementById('colorthis').getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var elem = a[i],
        color = colors[0];
    elem.style.color = color;
    colors.push(color);
    colors.shift();
}
```

Apprently this would work, but is there a way for me to apply this to the pseudo class of:

```
a:active
a:visited
```

Is this something jquery's .each could do?

Comment: Give the elements class names based on the color names, and then use CSS rules for the pseudo-classes.

Comment: to answer your question yes its possible to loop through a set of colors and yes you can use `.each` :)

Comment: do you really need to do it this way? like @Pointy said you can just use class names and then attach the events to change the class using jquery

Comment: It's because I'm trying to set up for a cms, so the user can just add a new post and it will automatically be a different colour.

Comment: @TomJulianHume the problem is that pseudo-class rules really have to be done with CSS rules, not on DOM element "style" objects. You can still do it for a CMS if you have your JavaScript add classes instead of directly modifying styles. That's better anyway since it makes theme possibilities so much broader.

Comment: Would it be possible to give me an example to how that would work? I'm at a loss here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
$.each(colors,function(key,val){
alert(key+ " "+val);
});
```

Comment: And how exactly will this allow for adding styles for the named pseudo-classes?